# Python script which looks for four smallest consecutive numbers with four unique prime factors

Tags: python, primes

For my school assignment I need to write a program which looks for the numbers with four unique prime factors and are consecutive. So far I got this code, but as result it yields wrong values. What do I do wrong?

```
# number to start with
n = 2

#function
def factor(x):
    factors = []
    i = 2
    while x > 1:
        if x % i == 0:
            x = x / i
            factors.append(i)
        else:
            i += 1
    factors = sorted(set(factors))
    return factors


#loop

while len(factor(n)) !=4 and len(factor(n+1)) !=4 and len(factor(n+2)) !=4 and len(factor(n+3)) !=4:
    n+=1


print "The first number is {}, the second number is {}, the third number is {}".format(n-3,n-2, n-1)
print "And the fourth number is {}".format(n)
```

Comment: Test the function factor() for small arguments, and then do some debugging.

Comment: The output 204, 205, 206 and 207. They have less than 4 unique prime factors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is spot on. I ran the code with the change and got `n = 34043`, which looks to be correct.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are right that the numbers in `range(204, 208)` don't have four factors:

```
>>> for x in range(204, 208):
    print x, factor(x)


204 [2, 3, 17]
205 [5, 41]
206 [2, 103]
207 [3, 23]
```

you have been misled by your code; you check `n, n+1, n+2, n+3` but show `n-3, n-2, n-1, n`. Your code stopped at `n == 207`, and if we add three to that:

```
>>> factor(210)
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

So your code stops when it finds the *first* number where `len(factor(x)) == 4`. Your logic is backwards; with a `while` loop like that, you want something that only evaluates `False` when you've found the answer. Evaluating your four predicates:

```
>>> True and True and True and False
False
```

Compare to the same predicates combined with `or`, instead:

```
>>> True or True or True or False
True
```

Now when all four numbers have four factors:

```
>>> False or False or False or False
False
```

---

I think you ended up with `and` because it follows the logic in your head more closely (*"I want the first one to be four, **and** the second one to be four, **and**..."*). On that basis, your code might be clearer as:

```
while True:
    if len(factor(n)) == 4 and len(factor(n+1)) == 4 and len(factor(n+2)) == 4 and len(factor(n+3)) == 4:
        break
    n += 1
```

or, more neatly (and obeying the style guide's line length limit!):

```
while True:
    if all(len(factor(x)) == 4 for x in range(n, n+4)):
        break
    n += 1
```